# Data warehousing using local DB - Beginner

Tags: database, data-warehouse

I want to get an idea on how to achieve this;

I have an application that runs at 5 different geographical locations. Eg: Texas, NY,California, Boston, Washington

This application saves data to a local database, which is located at that location.

I want to do data warehousing, So is it a must to have just have one database (Where all the 5 applications will now save its data in a single database - without having local DBs)

Or is it possible to have 5 local databases, and do data warehousing by retrieving data from those local DBs to a central DB and then performing data warehousing.

Please give me your thoughts and references.

Comment: You want to do data warehousing? Why? without a business need then you have no parameters to design the solution around. You can do any number of solutions (don't forget OLAP solutions) but without a business need or some constraints you have no idea which might be the best

Answer (score 1):

You have three options for this:

1. you use a single, centrally hosted database server. Typical relational database servers can be directly accessed via network these days: mySQL, Postgresql, Oracle, ... This means you can implement an application which opens a network connection to the database server and uses that remote server to store and retrieve the data as required. Multiple connections are possible at the same time.
2. you use a single, central database server but put a wrapper around it. So some small network layer application layer acting as a broker. This way you can address that central instance over network, but via standard protocols like for example http.
3. you use a decentralized approach and install a database instance at each location. Then you need some additional tool to perform a synchronization. For most modern database servers (see above) such tools exist, but the setup is not trivial.

If in doubt and if the load is not that high go with the first alternative.

Comment: Your 2nd approach is to read from all 5 database and save it in a separate DB for data warehousing ? Are there any reading materials on the above 3 approaches you recommend ?

Comment: No. The 2nd approach clearly states to have only a single database server at a central location. And about reading materials... I'd say every documentation of every database server addresses this. Just dive into the MySQL introduction online, or better even use the MariaDB variant.